Limit internet bandwith for a program
I'm running openSUSE Leap 15.5 on a Dell laptop connected to my broadband router by both Ethernet over power line and Wi-Fi. When I power up my laptop and log in, Internet access is very slow for a while. Investigation reveals that some program is using all the available download bandwidth. Since the Internet speeds up as soon as YaST tells me how many updates I have available, I suspect that the culprit is YaST checking for updates. Is there a way to limit the amount of Internet bandwidth that a particular program (YaST in this case) is allowed to use so that other activities are not slowed down? I could presumably disable YaST's automatic check for updates, but then I would not get informed when important security updates are available.
